# deleting records and adding between the records while doing infinite Scrolling in Java

Tags: java, infinite

1)  If we have 100 records in DB and we try to fetch only first 50 records (1-50), Order by LastUpdated Timestamp and displayed on the UI
2)  In the mean while someone has updated the record which was present at 100th position, now it will come to the 1st position.
3)  If we try to fetch next set of records (51-100), Order by LastUpdated TimeStamp then that record will not come and one duplicate record will be displayed this time, which has been modified by someone else. Since it’ll be at the 1st position in the DB.

I am using Spring PageListHolder for this.

It would be really helpful if someone can help me on this.

Comment: And what is your question/expected behaviour? Order by insertion order rather than timestamp?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to handle this situation. Actually i am implementing search application and we are providing infinite scrolling feature to the user.I don't want to fetch all records at one go, It'll impact on the performance.I want fetch some small set of records every time. But i'm facing duplicate data issue if someone has updated the record while i'm on the 2nd page of the Application.

Comment: Hence my question: What is the expected bahaviour? Only you can answer that. When will people ever see the updated ranking if it would never change? Note that e.g. Stack Overflow exhibits the same behaviour. If you scroll to page 2 of a tag with high frequency, you may find a question from page 1 again.